# Changing the Header Background

Tags: html, css

I have a forum @ http://forum.banaisbul.com

If you check the site you can see there's a problem with the header background. I want to change the entire header background to the color of the logo background. But I don't know which codes to put where.

Comment: Have you tried anything to accomplish this goal? Instead of just providing a link, show code that represents the issue you are facing

Comment: Brett hello. I cannot do that because I have zero knowledge of coding, I'm just a newbie wordpress user. What do you want me? to copy whole wordpress coding into the message?

Comment: No, please don't copy all of it. Part of learning how to manage a website is learning how to pull the code apart and find your issues. This process is commonly called debugging, and this is an important skill. What I would ask you to do is find the portion of your html that seems to be giving you an issue. To get a start on finding your problem, using the browser developer tools will probably be easiest : https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it you can simply add some CSS to the div that contains the header image.

```
<div class="imgheader">
    <img src="http://forum.banaisbul.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/banaisbulsiyah.jpg" border="0" alt="Link to this page">
</div>
```

Then in your CSS file out could do

```
.imgHeader{
    background-color: #3D3D3D;
}
```

Alternatively,

```
<div style="background-color: #3D3D3D">
</div>
```

The hardest part will likely be matching the CSS color hex code (e.g. #3D3D3D) to your image. You may want to look here to try to get an exact match : [Paletton.com](http://paletton.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Matthew Rath gave you the correct answer to the problem that you wrote. But the bigger problem that you have revealed is that you do not know how to use your resources. Take some time and learn to use your web developer tools (web inspector, etc). Then you can solve these issues quickly by yourself.

Comment: This probably should have been a a comment instead of an answer since it does not directly address the question presented..

Answer (score 1):

**It's `#404040` - Tested in Photoshop:**

**HTML:**

```
<div style="background-color: #404040;">
    <a href="http://forum.banaisbul.com">
        <img src="http://forum.banaisbul.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/banaisbulsiyah.jpg" border="0" alt="Link to this page">
    </a>
</div>
```

**Photoshop Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to style the container div which currently has no selector assigned to it:

http://puu.sh/blDRr.png

This being the case you could do:

```
.cnt-container > div {
background-color: "your colour"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also add it directly in your page-template (this is called 'inline styling'):

a couple of lines below your opening body tag you'll find

```
<div>
<a href="http://forum.banaisbul.com"><img src="http://forum.banaisbul.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/banaisbulsiyah.jpg" border="0" alt="Link to this page"></a>
</div>
```

and you need to change it to

```
<div style="background-color:#404040">
<a href="http://forum.banaisbul.com"><img src="http://forum.banaisbul.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/banaisbulsiyah.jpg" border="0" alt="Link to this page"></a>
</div>
```